# Как очищать консоль Python правильно, используя logger?

Tags: python

Я использую метод вывода в консоль через logger.info
Хочу удалять и заново писать строку, чтобы не было каши, пробовал через os.system, не вышло.

```
os.system('cls' if os.name == 'nt' else 'clear')
logger.info(f'Keys: {queue_api.qsize()} | id {str(Ids[i][16:27])}')
```

Comment: Посмотри пожалуйста [тут еще варианты](https://stackoverflow.com/q/517970/2546083).  Но 600+ человек подтвердили что работает. `os.system('cls')` `os.system('clear')`

Comment: чтобы не было каши. вы можете колоризировать разными цветами сообщения. либо ключевые слова в них. либо программа запускается, а к её логу командой tail -f file подключается grep.  это удобно в мониторинге дальнейшем